# How to use module loading in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, I have a code like this:

levenstein/LevensteinAlgorithm.ts

```
export module levenstein {
    export class LevensteinAlgorithm
    {
        getDistance(left: string, right: string): number {
        // Some code for the alogorithm...
        }
    }
}
```

To have a unit test for it, I have written a test in another path:

tests/levensteinAlgorithmTests.ts

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typings/qunit/qunit.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../levenstein/levensteinalgorithm.ts" />

QUnit.module("levensteinalgorithm.ts tests");

import levenstein = require("levenstein/LevensteinAlgorithm");

test("Simple update cost is equal to 1", ()=> {
// Arrange
var leven = new levenstein.LevensteinAlgorithm();

//...
```

Unfortunately it has a build error saying:

```
Property LevensteinAlgorithm doesn't exist on type: ....
```

I'm using *QUnit* and **Chutzpah** to run the tests.

What's the problem with my module loading?

Answer (score 2):

Because you wrapped `LevensteinAlgorithm` in the internal module `levenstein` in an external module, the way to reference that object once you've imported it as `levenstein` is `levenstein.levenstein.LevensteinAlgorithm`.

The best fix here is to just remove the `export module Levenstein {` from `LevensteinAlgorithm.ts` and export the class directly out of the external module.

See also the "Needless Namepsacing" heading here: https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript